# Return to specific page after login

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc, webapi

I'm sending email with approval link - that is pointing to page in the application where user can approve request.when user clicks on the email link it will redirect to login page if user is not already authenticated.
after login I want to redirect him to same page from the link.
How can I achieve this in angular 6.

Answer (score 0):

Import the router:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

Then, inject the router to your constructor:

```
constructor (router: Router)
```

Finally, add the following to your method after login is success:

```
let queryParams = this.router.routerState.snapshot.root.queryParams;
if (Object.keys(queryParams).length != 0 && queryParams.redirectUrl != null) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(queryParams.redirectUrl);
}
```

Just make sure your URL is correct, like: www.yourapp.com?redirectUrl=/pagetoredirect